# How can I write the following code if the database call is dependant on this.user?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, google-cloud-firestore

I subscribe to this.userService.current but sometimes it can take up some time to retrieve from database so when database is called to retrieve loads and I test if the user is a carrier it throws null on this.user.carrier. How do I wait for this.user to be resolved before calling database to retrieve loads collection.

```
    this.userService.currentUser.subscribe(user=>{
      this.user = user;
    });
    this.status$ = new BehaviorSubject("Active");
    this.loads$ = this.status$.switchMap(status => 
    afs.collection<Load>('loads', ref => { 
      if(this.user.carrier){
        ref.where('carrier','==', this.user.carrier.id)
      } 
      ref.where('status', '==', status)
      return ref
    }).valueChanges());
```

Comment: Why not just put all your code into the `userService` subscription?

Answer (score 0):

Anything that needs to be executed after an observable or promise is complete has to go in either the subscribe or then method.

```
this.userService.currentUser.subscribe(user=>{
  this.user = user;
  this.status$ = new BehaviorSubject("Active");
  this.loads$ = this.status$.switchMap(status => 
  afs.collection<Load>('loads', ref => { 
  if(this.user.carrier){
    ref.where('carrier','==', this.user.carrier.id)
  } 
  ref.where('status', '==', status)
  return ref
  }).valueChanges());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of a subscribe on a observable is a function which gets executed every time a new value comes from your observable. So the point here is to do your stuff inside this function, instead of outside like in your example.

It would look like this :

```
this.userService.currentUser.subscribe(user=>{
    this.user = user;

    this.status$ = new BehaviorSubject("Active");
    this.loads$ = this.status$.switchMap(status => 
        afs.collection<Load>('loads', ref => { 
        if(this.user.carrier){
           ref.where('carrier','==', this.user.carrier.id)
        } 
        ref.where('status', '==', status)
        return ref
    }).valueChanges());
});
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this but query's don't work.. I also tried using combine which essentially does exact same thing but again, the query doesn't run. It retrieves all loads.

Comment: means that the call to the database retrieves all records and doesn't apply the filter. return ref does nothing as if it is absorbed somewhere. If i move the switch map outside the the user subscription it works. But if I write it like you did it fails.

Comment: Do you see the code inside your switchMap running ? Because from what I can see, you don't subscribe to your BehaviorSubject status